# How to to import Excel into SQL Server without duplicates?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel

I have to upload Excel data into SQL Server. That data how to check and insert into previous table.

For example, previous table:

```
id name address  
1 mohan chennai  
2 raja madurai
```

Excel data

```
id name address  
1 ram covai  
2 mohan chennai
```

In this case I should only update `ram` into previous table, because `mohan` is already available in database table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Import skip duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422572/sql-import-skip-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. One way is to import your excel data into a temporary table the issue an insert into from temp table.

```
SELECT id, name, address
INTO yourtable d
FROM temp t
WHERE t.name not in (select name from yourtable)
```

Comment: I am importing data from Excel into a SQL Server database and its successfull, Is there any way ,while I can check if the current row exist in database before inserting that particular row from Excel?